# What's wrong with my implementation, using Date object's setDate function

Tags: javascript

I have a date object and I need to create another date object that is 1 week after the first date object. I already have an implementation but it seems that there is a bug with javascript when it reaches the months of October, November and December. Is there a workaround for this? Note that the behavior is consistent across Chrome, FF and IE.

```
        // ************ TEST#1 ************
        var startDate = new Date(2011,08,05); // set to Sept 5, 2011
        alert('START DATE' + startDate);

        var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);

        alert('END DATE' + endDate); // endDate is Sept 12 which is correct
        // check that startDate's value is unchanged
        alert('START DATE' + startDate); 


        // ************ TEST#2 ************
        var startDate = new Date(2011,10,05); // set to Nov 5, 2011
        alert('START DATE' + startDate);

        var endDate = new Date();
        endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);

        alert('END DATE' + endDate); // endDate is Sept 12, 2011 which is wrong
        alert('START DATE' + startDate);



        // ************ TEST#3 ************
        // changed implementation but this won't work
        var startDate = new Date(2011,10,05);
        alert('START DATE' + startDate);

        var endDate = startDate;
        endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);

        alert('END DATE' + endDate); // endDate is correct but...
        alert('START DATE' + startDate); // startDate's value has changed as well
```

Comment: Your first assumption should not be "it's a bug", but rather "what have I done wrong?".

Comment: After all those years of envelopment and millions of developers, you think that you will find such a bug?

Comment: [First rule of programming: It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: You're right. So what have I done wrong? =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your error might be that you are setting `endate` to today.

```
    // ************ TEST#2 ************
    var startDate = new Date(2011,10,05); // set to Nov 5, 2011
    alert('START DATE' + startDate);

    // edit
    var endDate = new Date(startDate.getFullYear(),startDate.getMonth(),startDate.getDate() + 7);
    // old var endDate = new Date();
    // endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 7);

    alert('END DATE' + endDate); // endDate is Sept 12, 2011 which is wrong
    alert('START DATE' + startDate);
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan. I cannot hard code endDate. My goal is for endDate to be 1 week after startDate, whatever startDate's value is.

Comment: @Aleks I've edited it to what I believe will do what your are looking for.  Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Works! (but +1 in month field is not needed). Thanks!

Comment: @Aleks Yep I though since the month was zero based it would need a +1 but then when i tested it my self I relized the the date field takes the zero based array, so i edited my awnser again and removed the +1 to the month.  I tested the end of the month as well. if you change the date to the 30th it will correctly roll to the next month.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug.  In this case `Date` is an object and both `startDate` and `endDate` refer to the same `Date` instance.  Hence when you change the underlying object it's visible through both references

**EDIT**

OP specified the bug is in Test #2

This is still not a bug.  The problem here is that `setDate` will only change the day of the month.  In this you've executed `startDate.getDate() + 7` where `startDate.getDate() === 5` so  it's correctly adjusting the date portion of `endDate` to the 12th of the month.

Comment: I understand this but I forgot to add that TEST#3 is just a different implementation to achieve my goal of having two date objects that is a week apart. The bug is actually in TEST#2.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to JaredPar, new Date() will create a date with current time, and if you only invoke .setDate() you will only change "day of month".

Comment: I see. My fault is misunderstanding the behavior of setDate. What should I have done in this case?

Comment: You can always instantiate a new date based on another date using the constructor: var x = new Date(oldDate); x.setDate(x.getDate() + 7); However, you are better of adding time as milliseconds: var x = new Date(oldDate.valueOf() + 7 * 86400 * 1000); 7 days times 86400 seconds per day times 1000 to get milliseconds.